# Как сделать ответ цветным

Tags: java

> Создайте программу-тест для проверки знаний таблицы умножения. С помощью случайных чисел создайте 5 примеров. При правильном ответе — на экране пишется Правильно зеленым цветом, при неправильном — Ошибка красным цветом. Также программа в зависимости от результата прохождения тест должна выставить оценку прохождения теста: если количество правильных ответов=5, то Молодец, 3 или 4, то Надо бы еще поучить, меньше 2 — Срочно нужно учить таблицу умножения.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int correctAnswers = 0;
    int Answers = 0;
    Random numGenerator = new Random();
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] nums =  new int[2];

    while(Answers != 5) {
        nums[0] = numGenerator.nextInt(9)+1;
        nums[1] = numGenerator.nextInt(9)+1;
        System.out.print(nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" = ");
        int answer = inputScanner.nextInt();
        ++Answers;
        if(answer == nums[0]*nums[1]) {
            System.out.println("Правильно.");
            ++correctAnswers;
        }
        else

            System.out.println("Неправильно. Попробуйте еще раз." );
    }
    System.out.println("Завершение.");
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста как сделать ответы цветными.И как выполнить оценивание ?

Comment: вам надо сделать консольное приложение или приложение с графическим интерфейсом? на какой ОС будет запускаться приложение?

Comment: Консольное. Делаю на NetBeans IDE 8.2, windows

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Выводить разными цветами можно при помощь ANSI кодов. Вот тебе класс для облегчения работы.

**Interface ANSIColors**

```
public enum  ANSIColors {

   RESET("\u001B[0m"),
   RED("\u001B[31m"),
   GREEN("\u001B[32m"),
   YELLOW("\u001B[33m"),
   BLUE("\u001B[34m"),
   PURPLE("\u001B[35m"),
   CYAN("\u001B[36m");

   private String val;

   ANSIColors(String val){
       this.val = val;
   }

   public String getVal(){
       return this.val;
   }
}
```

Пример:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message.print("Hello World", ANSIColors.BLUE);
        Message.print("Hello World", ANSIColors.RED);
        Message.print("Hello World", ANSIColors.PURPLE);
        Message.print("Hello World", ANSIColors.YELLOW);
    }

    abstract static class Message{
        static void print(String message, ANSIColors color){
            System.out.println(color.getVal() + message + ANSIColors.RESET.getVal());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Задача она на то и задача, уже ее решай сам

Comment: это не является ответом на вопрос. если вы хотите дать вопрошающему совет, то используйте комментарии под вопросом.